# How can I bind the RadioButton Content property value to a TextBlock Text in a Style?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this style for a RadioButton on WPF

```
<Style x:Key="UserRadioButton" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Border
                        x:Name="border"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        CornerRadius="5">

                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <fa:IconImage MaxHeight="50" Icon="User" />
                                <TextBlock
                                    Width="Auto"
                                    Height="Auto"
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the TextBlock Text it's not Binding to the content

I tried to use different properties to bind but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

`ContentPresenter` does not allow content to be defined using XAML content syntax. This is because the `ContentPresenter` does not derive from `ContentControl`. The `ConTentControl` type is decorated with the `ContentPropertyAttribute` attribute which is inherited to all inheritors. And `ContentPresenter` does not apply the `ContentPropertyAttribute` itself. Therefore, `ContentPresenter` does not support XAML content syntax.

The `ContentPresenter` is used inside the template of a `ContentControl` to actually render the value of the `ContentControl.Content` property. Because it supports templating, it can render any content.
If you override the `Controltemplate` of a `ContentControl` (e.g. `RadioButton`) you usually you would embed a `ContentPresenter` into the new layout.
In your case you are trying to replace the `ContentPresenter` by adding a `TextBlock` to render the content. This limits the reusability significantly as now the content can only be a `string`. For this reason, the recommended way is to embed the `ContentPresenter` into you extended layout. You always want to show the `ContentControl.Content` value so you always would embed the `ContentPresenter`.

Also don't set `Border` attributes like `Background` property locally as this eliminates customization by assignig local values on the templated parent (for example `RadioButton Background="Red" />` won't work anymore).
Instead use `TemplateBinding` to bind those properties to the owner of the `ControlTemplate` and set the default values using `Style.Setters`.

**Recommended solution**
Embed the `ContentPresenter` into the custom layout:

```xml
<Style x:Key="UserRadioButton"
       TargetType="RadioButton">
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="Black" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
          Value="2" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Border x:Name="border"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                CornerRadius="5">
          <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <fa:IconImage MaxHeight="50" 
                          Icon="User" />

            <!-- 
                 Automatically shows the value of the Content property .
                 and also inherits properties like FontSize, FontWeight etc.
                 from the templated parent control.
            -->
            <ContentPresenter />
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

For the sake of completeness, below are different variants you can use if you want to replace the `ContentPresenter` with your `TextBlock`.
Note that non of those examples below are recommended solutions.

**Example 1 (not recommended)**
Set `ContentPrersenter.Content` explicitly:

```xml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
  <Border x:Name="border"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
          CornerRadius="5">
    <ContentPresenter>

      <!-- 
           The XAML content syntax is not supported by the ContentPresenter.
           However, we can use the XAML property element syntax to set the Content:
      -->
      <ContentPresenter.Content>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
          <fa:IconImage MaxHeight="50" 
                        Icon="User" />
          <TextBlock Width="Auto"
                     Height="Auto"
                     FontSize="16"
                     Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </StackPanel>
      <ContentPresenter.Content>
    </ContentPresenter>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Example 2 (not recommended)**
Simply drop the `ContentPrersenter` from the layout as its content was already explicitly defined in example 1 what effectively makes the `ContentPresenter` pointless:

```xml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
  <Border x:Name="border"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
          CornerRadius="5">

    <!-- 
         Because the Content is presented using the TextBlock 
         the ContentPresenter has no more use and can be dropped from the layout.
    -->
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <fa:IconImage MaxHeight="50" 
                    Icon="User" />
      <TextBlock Width="Auto"
                 Height="Auto"
                 FontSize="16"
                 Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
    </StackPanel>      
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Example 3 (recommended for some scenarios, for example when the original layout and interaction behavior, like mouse over state effects, should be preserved)**
A more useful alternative is to define the value for `ContentControl.Content` inline either directly on the element for example

```xml
<!-- 
     This solution will preserve the original layout, 
     like the circle that highlights the toggle state, 
     and interaction behavior
-->
<RadioButton>
  <RadioButton.Content> 
    <TextBlock Text="Some text" /> 
  </RadioButton.Content> 
</RadioButton>
```

or with the help of a `Style` :

```xml
<!-- 
     This solution will preserve the original layout, 
     like the circle that highlights the toggle state, 
     and interaction behavior
-->
<Style x:Key="UserRadioButton"
       TargetType="RadioButton">
  <Setter Property="Content">
    <Setter.Value>
      <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <fa:IconImage MaxHeight="50" 
                      Icon="User" />

        <!-- 
             This example binds the the TextBlock.Text property 
             to the current DataContext of the styled control (RadioButton).
        -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding textPropertyOfDataContext}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Example 4 (recommended for some scenarios, for example when the original layout and interaction behavior, like mouse over state effects, should be preserved)**
Another useful alternative is to define the value for `ContentControl.Content` by defining a `DataTemplate` for the `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` property:

```xml
<!-- 
     This solution will preserve the original layout, 
     like the circle that highlights the toggle state, 
     and interaction behavior
-->
<Style x:Key="UserRadioButton"
       TargetType="RadioButton">
  <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
          <fa:IconImage MaxHeight="50" 
                        Icon="User" />

          <!-- 
               This example binds then TextBlock.Text property 
               to the current DataContext of the DataTemplate 
               which is the ContentControl.Content value.
          -->
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```